# Keras(theano) error while gpu

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, keras, theano

Already long time I try to understand with a problem. Please help me.

I'm trying to run the 'Keras' example from the standard example git lib ([there](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py)).

If I use CPU, then everything will works fine; But, If I try to use GPU acceleration, it will crash WITHOUT catching any errors:

```
# build the model: a single LSTM
print('Build model...')
print('   1')
model = Sequential()
print('   2')
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars))))
print('   3')
model.add(Dense(len(chars)))
print('   4')
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

print('   5')
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)

print('   Compilling')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

I put some `print()` for better understand the place of error. 
And what I get:

```
runfile('C:/Users/kostya/Desktop/temp/python/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/kostya/Desktop/temp/python/')
Using Theano backend.
Using cuDNN version 5110 on context None
Preallocating 1638/2048 Mb (0.800000) on cuda
Mapped name None to device cuda: GeForce GTX 650 (0000:01:00.0)
WARNING: Preallocating too much memory can prevent cudnn and cublas from working properly
DEVICE: cuda
corpus length: 206433
total chars: 79
nb sequences: 68798
Vectorization...
Build model...
   1
   2


Ядро остановилось, перезапуск *(It means: The Core has stopped, restarting)*
```

I will take Similar error, if I run it througth standatr python console. *(python.exe emergency stops)*

I use: Win 10-64, Python 3.6.1, Anaconda with activated separate enviroment, CUDA 8.0, cuRNN 5.1, mkl 2017.0.3, numpy 1.13.0, theano 0.9.0, conda-forge.keras 2.0.2, m2w64-openblas 0.2.19, conda-forge.pygpu 0.6.8, VC 14.0 etc.

That's my `.theanorc.txt` configurational file. *(I'm sure this can catch him. **If I put the `device = cpu` - it works fine** (but slowly))*

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = cuda
optimizer_including = cudnn

[nvcc]
flags=-LC:\Users\kostya\Anaconda3\envs\keras\libs
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0

[dnn]
library_path = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64
include_path = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include

[gpuarray]
preallocate = 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You trying to use `gpuarray` backend option (`preallocate`) with CUDA backend. From Theano [doc](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#config.config.gpuarray.preallocate):

> This value allocates GPU memory ONLY when using (GpuArray Backend). For the old backend, please see config.lib.cnmem

Try replace in your Theano config

```
[gpuarray]
preallocate = 0.8
```

with

```
[lib]
cnmem = 0.8
```

Comment: Thank you, But it does not work.
In this case, it does not even allocate a memory of 0.8. 
I use CUDA 8.0 and Theano 0.9.0 which support the GpuArray Backend.